# How do I use the numpy.savetxt function to save this array to a specifc folder?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to save this array then move it to a folder but it will not allow me too because it is not the right type I do not think. I cannot seem to figure it out so any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I am trying to use. The `location` variable I have defined as the path to the folder I want to move it to after saving.

I did this and it worked when the array has only one dimension (if `b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]`) but if I add another element in front such like I did in the code I posted, it won't work.

```py
import numpy as np
import shutil
b = [5,np.array([1,2,2,3,6,7])]
np.savetxt('hi',b)
shutil.move('hi',location)
```

I got the following error message:

`Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')`

Comment: Look at `np.array(b)`.  Is that a nice 2d numeric array?

Comment: The error occurs in the `savetxt` and is caused by a badly formed `b`.  Show us what you want the resulting file to look like, and we might suggest a fix.  Remember `savetxt` works best when given a 2d numeric array.  Don't pass a list.

Answer (score 0):

Savetxt only saves array-like objects. So when b is the original array it will work fine. In the code above you set b to be a list containing the number 5 and an array.

I'm not quite sure where you want that five to end up, but you will need to insert it into the actual array. You might want to use the insert method to put the value at the beginning of the array such as

```
   b = np.insert(b,0,5)
```

I might also add that you can save the file directly to the location that you would like to, which would eliminate the need for `shutil`. Just specify a path to the location you would like to save the file that is valid given where the program is run and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks this helps, for the numpy.savetxt function, where does the path go? From what I have been doing it seems it goes np.savetxt(filename,data), assuming 'data' is the thing you are saving

Comment: The path is included in the filename. So if you wanted to save it in a subdirectory called 'hello', the filename would be 'hello/hi'